# Why does 'œ' match 'oe' in an NVarchar but not in a Varchar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replace

```
SELECT REPLACE(N'Chloe', 'œ', 'o'), REPLACE('Chloe', 'œ', 'o')
```

Results in:

```
Chlo    Chloe
```

This is super weird.

---

Another way:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN N'œ' = N'oe' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as NVarcharMatch,
  CASE WHEN 'œ' = 'oe' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as VarcharMatch
```

Results in:

```
NVarCharMatch   VarcharMatch
1   0
```

Comment: i'm getting both as `Chlo` . Can you please explain to reproduce the case?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the collation of the database/server.

Comment: This might be useful to you: http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=U%2B0153

Comment: I found a collation that works.  Try this:  `SELECT REPLACE(N'Chloe' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, N'œ', N'o'), REPLACE('Chloe', 'œ', 'o')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both legacy SQL collations ("SQL" collation prefix) and binary collations ("BIN" prefix compare only single characters at a time so "œ" can never equal "oe".

Windows collations and Unicode comparison use more robust comparison rules. This allows the single "œ" character to compare as equal to the 2 consecutive characters "oe" because they are semantically identical.

```
--Chlo because Unicode comparison equal
SELECT REPLACE(N'Chloe' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, 'œ', 'o'); 

--Chloe because legacy SQL comparison unequal
SELECT REPLACE('Chloe' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, 'œ', 'o'); 

--Chloe because binary comparison unequal
SELECT REPLACE('Chloe' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, 'œ', 'o');

--Chlo because Windows collation comparison equal
SELECT REPLACE('Chloe' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, 'œ', 'o');
```